# How to catch specific exception in CoroutineExceptionHandler

Tags: kotlin, exception, kotlin-coroutines

I have this CoroutineExceptionHandler:

```
private val handler: CoroutineExceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler{ _, exception ->
println(“Exception thrown in one of the children: $exception”)
}
```

Can I catch specific exceptions (like with try…catch) for example I want to catch java.net.SocketException. Try…catch around the code doesn’t work and I want to alert the user when server closes the connection.

Comment: can you show the code snippet of how you are creating your coroutine?